# Meaning of куда мне

Tags: idioms

I saw the following exchange:

> Будешь поступать в институт? 
>   - **Куда мне**, мне б в училище поступить".

Since there's no question mark, I'm led to believe that куда мне is rhetorical here, and quite possibly an idiom. (Also, I admit, I don't really know what the second sentence means).

Comment: also `(да) куда там?`, `(да) где уж (там)?`, `(да) где (уж) (там) мне/нам/ему/тебе etc?`

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка: Thank you very much for your answer - I have no idea what to make of it.

Comment: these are just synonyms to `куда мне?`

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. I thought you were asking me something :) So these can be used in the same way?

Comment: yep, they certainly can.... also `(да) какой там?` only that this denotes impossibility/skepticism about chances due to unfavorable circumstances rather than incapability

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Куда** as a particle may ironically express a negation, doubt, or impossibility.

It may be translated as a rhetorical question:

> Болею уже несколько дней: **куда там** работать!
> *I've been sick for several days. How am I supposed to work?!*
>
> Куда же мне петь! Голоса нет.
> *How am I supposed to sing? I have no voice!*

Answer (score 7):

You are right, `куда мне` (and also `куда ему`, `куда им` etc) is an idiom that means:

> I'm not *good* / *smart* / *skilled* enough.

So the second sentence could be translated as:

> I'm not *smart* enough for university — I hope to get into a trade school.

Answer (score 5):

*Куда* with the dative (*куда мне*, *куда тебе*, *куда им*) is used to skeptically express doubt. In your example, it can be translated as "(I don't think) I'm able to do it — I'd be happy just to be admitted into a vocational school."

Answer (score 3):

Куда is a particle, colloquial, used with pronouns in the Dative (куда мне, куда ему, куда нам, etc.) to express **doubt, skepticism**

> **куда тебе** до него! **you'll never be able to do** it like him!
> куда мне, мне б в училище поступить.— I'm not so smart (I can't do it) — I'd be happy just to get into a vocational school.
> Куда мне in general means that my skillset/knowledge isn't high enough to get or to reach something. Or I can't do something due to certain circumstances.